# Dropdown not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

im facing issue when i switched to arabic language using TranslatePress plugin in my wordpress website.

https://xplood.com/product/queens/?lang=ar

Colors and size options not working in arabic only and look a likes TranslatePress broke something that cost data value not showing !!

Arabic Html:

```
<option value="White" class="attached enabled"></option>
```

English Html:

```
<option value="White" class="attached enabled">White</option>
```

Hope there a solution like Css or Javascript, JQuery that will solve my issue..

Thanks.

Comment: please share your plugin code or change the plugin. you already identified the problem that your plugin is causing this issue

Comment: the plugin convert ltr to lrt that broke the ajax of the page then the dropdown not showing that the problem ... all i want to stop the plugin to convert to lrt or any solution !!